# How to smoothly change the background of this circle progress bar from maximum value to 0?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, gauge

I have a circle progress bar which imitates a car speedometer, I have successfully made it change its value smoothly but now i want to introduce another feature where it has a default value of 80 on component start and then quickly goes to 0 in a smooth manner, by smooth I mean it does not jump over the progress bar circle but gradually decrease its value.

I tried with my code below where I check if the value of `initialShowSpeed` is true and if true, i try to make the percent value 0 but then it just makes the progress bar disappear immediately and I don't want that, i want it to disappear in a second or two but smoothly, I see the whole transition from maximum value to 0.

Here is my current code in react.js styled components:

```
  
const CircleProgress = styled.div`
  transition: ${({ initialShowSpeed }) => (initialShowSpeed ? 'background 0.5s ease-in' : 'background 1.5s ease')};

  position: relative;
  height: 480px;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(${theme.colors.secondary} 
  ${({ percentage }) => handleDegPercantage(percentage)}deg, 
  #0F0F0F 0deg);

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);

  &::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0F0F0F;
  }
`;

useEffect(() => {
    setPercent(calculatePercantge(0, 80, speed || 0)); // max 80 min 0
  }, [calculatePercantge, speed]);

  const [animatedPercent, setAnimatedPercent] = useState(0);
  const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(0);


  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;

    if (Math.abs(animatedPercent - percent) > 0.1) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {

        // Calculate the difference between the current animatedPercent and the target percent
        const delta = percent - animatedPercent;

        if (delta > 0.1 && animatedPercent === 0) {
          setAnimatedPercent(percent || 0);
        }
        
        // Stop the interval if the difference is small enough
        if (Math.abs(delta) < 0.1) {
          setAnimatedPercent(percent);
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {

              // Otherwise, update animatedPercent in the direction of percent
            const change = delta > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1; // 0.1 -0.1
            setAnimatedPercent((prev) => prev + change);
         
        }
      }, initialShowSpeed ? 3 : 20); // Adjust this time to speed up or slow down the animation // 20
    }

    // Clean up the interval when the component unmounts or the percent changes
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [percent, animatedPercent]);

  return (
    <TestCircle>
      <OuterCircle onClick={() => changeUnit(measureUnit)}>
        {/* <DashedCircle radius={295} numberOfDashes={30} /> */}

        <CircleProgress initialShowSpeed={initialShowSpeed} percentage={animatedPercent || 0}> {/* animatedPercent */}
          <SpeedContainer>
            <Text
              textElements={[
                {
                  // value: speed !== null && speed !== undefined ? speed : 0,
                  value: speed || 0,
                  fontSize: '154px', // 124px
                  color: 'white',
                },
                {
                  value: measureUnit || 'M/S',
                  fontSize: '24px',
                  color: 'white',
                },
              ]}
              flexDirection="column"
              justifyContent="center"
              alignItems="center"
            />
          </SpeedContainer>
        </CircleProgress>
      </OuterCircle>
    </TestCircle>
  );
}
```